# Getting the Store Name in a Block

Tags: magento2, variables

Is it possible to output the store name using double curly brace syntax?

For example, I know I can output the contact page's URL using:

```
<a href="{{store url="contact"}}">Contact Luma</a>
```

Is there a way I can do something like this:

```
<p>Hi, welcome to {{store name}}! We hope you like it here.</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get store name like this:

**In Phtml:**

```
$storeName = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();
```

**In Cms Page:**

```
{{config path="general/store_information/name"}}
```

Don't forget to configure your store name from below Configuration path:

**admin->system->configuration, general->store information** select the store in top left corner and set the name of your store that you want to show.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. I hadn't set the store name, that's why I was getting a blank. I had to go to Dashboard, Stores, Settings, Configuration, General, Store Information, Store Name, enter the store's name, Save Config.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
{{config path="general/store_information/name"}}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it didn't work. I'm trying to add the text in a CMS page (not a PHP template).

Comment: your other changes are applying to CMS page ? because @Rafael answer should work.